# Error filling and distributing values on the x-axis of the bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a bar graph in ggplot, considering a "type" variable in the filling of each bar.

However, the maximum values of the bars are excessively high (above 100, when in fact they should be close to 40). My goal is to place the overlay padding.

I appreciate any help.

```
df <- structure(list(Count = c("Beu", "Beu", "Beu", "Abe", "Abe", "Abe", 
"Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Bra", "Bra", "Bra"), Type = c(1, 2, 3, 
1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), Hours = c(40.17775, 42.1492178098676, 
42.1910353866317, 38.3701812919564, 39.9185282522996, 38.8002722361139, 
41.6389448017412, 41.7041742286751, 41.9545826200271, 41.1375910844406, 
41.0602923264312, 40.6300999927013)), row.names = c(NA, 12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here's the code I'm trying to run:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Type = as.factor(Type)) %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Count, y = Hours, fill = Type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To overlay the bars you could add `position = 'identity'` in your `geom_bar` with a lower transparency `alpha` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(Type = as.factor(Type)) %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Count, y = Hours, fill = Type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'identity', alpha =0.2) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Another option is by dodging your bars using `position_identity` to have them overlayed and to make sure the highest values are behind you can `arrange` the values per group like this:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(Type = as.factor(Type)) %>% 
  group_by(Count) %>%
  arrange(desc(Hours)) %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Count, y = Hours, fill = Type)) +
  geom_bar (stat="identity", position =position_identity()) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much @Quinze. Is it possible to change the colors?

Comment: hi @Erivelton, Check my updated answer! You could also overlay your bars and place the highest values behind like above!

Answer (score 0):

If Quinten did not answer as you expected, I would use a dodged method to show each category in a bar to itself as such:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Type = Type) %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Count, y = Hours, fill = as.factor(Type))) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity',position = 'dodge2') +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic()
 theme_classic()
```

This would give you this chart:[image]

Comment: This is preferable... with `position = "identity"` it's hard to tell what the actual values are as people will read it as a stacked bar chart (with or without `alpha`).